# Django: don't let users view views/template if not logged in on admin

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django. I would like to know if is it possible for Anonymous users not to access my views/template page if they are not logged in to django admin?

**Example:**

```
localhost/myviews
localhost/admin
```

Anonymous user access localhost/myviews > authenticate if logged in to admin > if not, throw error

Comment: With django.contrib.admin, authentification as admin is required to access admin interface if that is your question. And django doesn't directly serves your templates, it renders it before through views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the decorator @login_required. See [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required).

`from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(login_url='/login'/) 
def secret(request): 
    return render(request,'after_login.html', {})`

Comment: Actually if you want only admins to see the view - and by admins you mean users with the `staff` flag set - you can actually go one step further and use the [@staff_member_required decorator](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/views/decorators.py#L5) instead. Or if you want to implement your own condition whether the user has permission to get the view, you can as well play with the [@user_passes_test or the @permission_required decorator](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c1aec0feda73ede09503192a66f973598aef901d/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py).

Comment: That should do it.. Thanks!